# Process output doesn't write last line

Tags: c#, process

I'm making a GUI for a console program. Sometimes it requires a input like a password, so if the output contains "password" it opens a dialog.

The problem is that the output doesn't print the line "Enter your password" but running the console it does.

> Opening...
>   Reading configuration...
>   Enter your password:            <- This appear in the console, but not the GUI.

Process:

```
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--server";
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.Domain = "";
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ASF.exe";
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.Password = null;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = null;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = null;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "";
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
this.ASFProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
this.ASFProcess.SynchronizingObject = this;
this.ASFProcess.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(this.ASFProcess_OutputDataReceived);
this.ASFProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(this.ASFProcess_ErrorDataReceived);
```

Methods:

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ASFProcess.Start();
    ASFProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    ASFProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    ASFProcess.WaitForExit();
}

private void ASFProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    rtbOutput.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
    rtbOutput.SelectionStart = rtbOutput.Text.Length;
    rtbOutput.ScrollToCaret();
    if (e.Data.Contains("password"))
    {
        var enterPassword = new EnterPassword();
        enterPassword.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

> The OutputDataReceived event indicates that the associated Process has
>   written a
>
> line, terminating with a newline character, to its redirected
>   StandardOutput stream.

So I would suggest that the problem with the ASF.exe program is that on the line where it prompts for the password that it is not sending a newline character before it expects input.

I would suggest changing the way your ASF program works, or trying to read from the Standard & Error output streams in another way.

This might help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx